# Why is sometimes .data section virtual size bigger than raw size?

Tags: windows, portable-executable

Recently I found out, that .data section in PE can have virtual size bigger than raw size (in file). This is quite suprising. Some people say that this is an effect of uninitialized data somewhere.

But after analyzing some PE, I can't really find this extra data. Here is link to PEDump results of some program:

["Hello world" PEDump](http://pedump.me/9a0f897efa3d8af1d027cd760c24e514/#pe)

As you can see, .data section has bigger virtual size than raw size. Why is it like this in this particular example?

Answer (score 1):

Values for any initialized data is stored in the section, if the binary wants to reserve space in memory for any *uninitialized* data, then the virtual size will be larger than the raw data size.

You won't find this data in the file, because it doesn't need to be there. The addresses that reference the data (in the code section) are baked into the binary so that they will point to the correct location when it is loaded into memory.

If the loader didn't reserve this space up front, then globals, etc. would have to be allocated on the heap before they could be used.

From the [PE spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx):

> [SizeOfRawData is the] size of the section (for object files) or the
>   size of the initialized data on disk (for image files). For executable
>   images, this must be a multiple of FileAlignment from the optional
>   header. If this is less than VirtualSize, the remainder of the section
>   is zero-filled. Because the SizeOfRawData field is rounded but the
>   VirtualSize field is not, it is possible for SizeOfRawData to be
>   greater than VirtualSize as well. When a section contains only
>   uninitialized data, this field should be zero.

Edit: Respond to the question about the SizeOfUninitializedData.

The `SizeOfUninitializedData` field in the Optional Header is just the size of the `.bss` section (or the sum of them if there are multiple). Your binary didn't have a separate section for that data, so it was zero. Since sections are aligned on specific boundaries, it may be more efficient to save some space at the end of an existing section than to use a separate one.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand your answer, difference is from size of uninitialized data, but as you can see in the link I provided, size of uninitialized data is 0.

Comment: Still not clear :) so, you mean that my .data section is in fact .data + .bss? And that we need to reserve virtual memory for it, but since it will be filled with 0s we align raw size as if there is no .bss? (Maybe I just said something terribly wrong :) )

Comment: is this really all there is to it? afaik, when a large data structure must be initialised at runtime but is f.e. zero-initialised, the linker would just write something like "2000 x zero at this point" and dismiss it. then when the interpreter comes to work, he sets this up in the process rather than the binary